# Split string on * character regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to split a string in two on the '*' character, I have the following sentence : `This is * test string`

and I have written this code

```
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\*");
            string[] substrings = regex.Split(text);

            foreach (string match in substrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
            }
```

But I get the following output:

```
'T'h'i's' 'i's'....
```

But I desire:

```
'This is ' ' test string'
```

Any ideas how to correct my regex?

Edit : My sentence may have more than one '*' character, in which case i would need three sentences, e.g :

```
This is * test *
```

Comment: I may have more than one '*' in a sentence, will String.split work?

Comment: Bookmark [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). I go on it everytime I have a question about regex

Comment: Isn't `@"..."` a verbatim string (ie: no escaping necessary for the backslash)?  If so, `@"\\*"` would split by zero or more backslashes (that is, between each char).

Comment: @MattMcGrath : Yes. It will split it into multipe strings at the char you specify.  You can even have several different characters to break on.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Remove the double escape from you regular expression:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*");
```

...

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*");
String text = "This is * test * more * test";
string[] substrings = regex.Split(text);

foreach (String match in substrings)
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
```

Output

```
'This is '
' test '
' more '
' test'
```

Answer (score 5):

> "I may have more than one '*' in a sentence, will String.split work?"

Yes, you can achieve what you're trying to do with `String.Split()` as well:

```
var text = "This is * test *";

var substrings = text.Split('*');
```

This will give you an array with three strings.

> "This is "
>
> " test "
>
> ""

The final string is an empty string, which you can omit by using the method overload that accepts a `StringSplitOptions` value:

```
var substrings =
    text.Split(new[] {'*'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your expected output below code might help:

```
string text = "This is * test string";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*");
string[] substrings = regex.Split(text);
string output = "";
foreach (string match in substrings)
{   
    output += match;
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```